# specific type of illuminated push switch

Tags: button

(editing to try and remove from 'old hold' status)

I've been looking for a specific type of push switch for a little arduino/pi project I'm working on - it's the sort of illuminated push switch that you see on TV mixing boards like the one in the picture below (the orange ones at the bottom of the board)

Specific properties I'd like:

- Can take some text printed on the button face (assume printed on acetate)
- low voltage (LED) illumination.

If anyone knows what I can google for (I realize now that one is not really allowed to ask for specific links to shopping sites)

**Edited to add**

The links that folks have posted below are really helpful - thanks for that.

[image: This]

Comment: Tried the distributor sites yet?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/UBIlluminated.pdf Note the accessory snap-on keycaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/) has this [Monome](http://monome.org/devices/)-inspired [4x4 button pad](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/7835), to which you'll want to add their [Breakout PCB](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8033), along with diodes and the LEDs of your choice. They also have a [2x2 button pad](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/7836).

Comment: Those are soft silicone carbon contact buttons rather than the rigid actuator buttons the asker is talking about.